# Is it bug laravel, or what? hasMany return empty array

Tags: laravel

I don't know what the problem here, it just return empty array.

cars table ( Brio, Xpander, Lancer, Jazz )

```
Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->mediumIncrements('car_id');
    $table->string('Model', 255);
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('brand_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('brand_id')->on('brands');
    $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
    $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
});
```

brands table ( Honda, Toyota, Suzuki, Lexus )

```
Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->tinyIncrements('brand_id');
    $table->string('brand_name', 100);
    $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
    $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
});
```

Brand model

```
public function cars() {
    return $this->hasMany(Car::class, 'brand_id', 'car_id');
```

Controller

```
$collections = Brand::find(1); // Honda

foreach ($collections->cars as $car) {
    echo $car;
} // empty array
```

But if i switch position foreign key in Brand model to third argument (`car_id`, `brand_id`).

It return array but by `car_id`, its means only 1 car return. how to return cars by brand model?

Comment: which laravel version you are using??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon It fixed now. i wrong to understand `foreign key` and `local key` in documentation. when i put `brand_id, brand_id`. It works as expected.